# Template alias visibility in nested class

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, nested-class, template-aliases

Consider the following:

```
template<typename X>
struct Z {};

struct A
{
    using Z = ::Z<int>;

    struct B : Z
    {
        using C = Z;
    };
};
```

This compiles fine. Nice. But now add another parameter in `Z`:

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
struct Z {};

struct A
{
    template<typename X>
    using Z = ::Z<X, int>;

    struct B : Z<B>
    {
        using C = Z<B>;  // error: too few template arguments for class template 'Z'
    };
};
```

Ok, maybe it makes sense that the definition of template alias `Z` in class `A` is visible when deriving nested class `B`, but not inside its body, triggering the error since the global definition of `Z` has two parameters.

But **why** is the behavior different in the first case, when `Z` is just a type alias in `A`?

Finally, make `A` a template:

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
struct Z {};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    template<typename X>
    using Z = ::Z<X, int>;

    struct B : Z<B>
    {
        using C = Z<B>;
    };
};
```

Now the error is gone. **Why?**

(Tested on Clang 3.6 and GCC 4.9.2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: Deriving from a specialization of `Z` introduces the *injected-class-name* of `::Z`, which is found before the alias template. If `A` is a template, however, the *injected-class-name* is not found anymore because the base class of `B` is dependent.

---

Consider [temp.local]/1:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an
>   *injected-class-name* (Clause 9). **The *injected-class-name* can be used
>   as a *template-name* or a *type-name***.

And [basic.lookup]/3:

> The *injected-class-name* of a class (Clause 9) is also **considered to be a member of that class for the purposes of name […] lookup**.

`Z` is looked up as an unqualified name; [basic.lookup.unqual]/7:

[image]

Thus, the *injected-class-name* `Z` is found as a member of the base class  `Z<B, int>`, and used as a *template-name*, which renders your second program ill-formed. In fact, your first snippet uses the *injected-class-name* as well - the following snippet won't compile:

```
struct A
{
    using Z = ::Z<float>;
    struct B : ::Z<int>
    {
        static_assert( std::is_same<Z, ::Z<float>>{}, "" );
    };
};
```

Finally, if `A` is made a template, note that `B` is a dependent type as per [temp.dep.type]/(9.3)<sup>1</sup>, thus `Z<B>` is a dependent type as per [temp.dep.type]/(9.7), thus the **base class `Z<B>` is not examined during lookup for the *unqualified-id* `Z`** according to [temp.dep]/3:

> In the definition of a class [..], the scope of a
>   dependent base class (14.6.2.1) is not examined during unqualified
>   name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or
>   member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

Hence the *injected-class-name* won't be found.

---

<sup>1</sup> `B` is a "nested class [..] that is a *dependent member* of the current instantiation" (emphasis mine), since

> A name is a *dependent member* of the current instantiation if it is a
>   member of the current instantiation that, when looked up, refers to at
>   least one member of a class that is the current instantiation.

Comment: Wow. This is quite clear, thanks. The error actually appeared when `A` stopped being a template, which I thought would simplify the code a lot. However, I am now forced to use two different names for the two `Z`'s, which only makes the code uglier. If there is any better workaround, please let me know.

Comment: @iavr What about `using C = Z;`? (Won't work for `A` being a template)

Comment: Now that's impressive :-) Yes, it works on this simplified code here, but not on my original one (`unknown type name 'Z'`). I'll have to check where the difference is. `A` is not a template any more, and I intend to keep it that way.

Comment: Ah, it was because I had renamed the outer `Z` (say, to `Z1`). Now it's working and really simplified because I don't need `using C ...` at all. Great, thanks again!